# Chef server - recipes don't update in webui after cookbook uploaded

Tags: chef-infra

I created a cookbook "starter" with recipe default.rb including below content, then uploaded to chef server.

```
package 'httpd' do  
    action :install
end

service 'httpd' do  
    action [ :enable, :start ]
end

cookbook_file '/var/www/index.html' do  
  source 'index.html'  
  mode '0644'
end
```

Then I modified something as below and uploaded again:

```
package 'httpd' do  
    action :install
end

service 'httpd' do  
    action [ :enable, :start ]
end

cookbook_file '/var/www/html/index.html' do  
  source 'index.html'  
  mode '0644'
  owner 'root'
end
```

But from the web management console of chef server, I found the recipe content was not changed, however, the chef client can execute the updated recipe!
Anyone can help?

```
Starting Chef Client, version 12.5.1
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["starter"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - starter (1.0.0)
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 3 resources
Recipe: starter::default
  * yum_package[httpd] action install (up to date)
  * service[httpd] action enable (up to date)
  * service[httpd] action start (up to date)
  * cookbook_file[/var/www/html/index.html] action create
    - create new file /var/www/html/index.html
    - update content in file /var/www/html/index.html from none to 884675
    --- /var/www/html/index.html        2015-10-23 10:45:14.511812840 +0800
    +++ /var/www/html/.index.html20151023-1416-bq7485   2015-10-23 10:45:14.511812840 +0800
    @@ -1 +1,6 @@
    +<html>
    +<body>  
    +   <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    +</body>
    +</html>
    - change mode from '' to '0644'
    - change owner from '' to 'root'

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 1/4 resources updated in 02 seconds
```

Comment: Did you try hitting ctrl+F5 ? Sounds like a browser cache issue

Comment: Did you actually update the version of the cookbook in `metadata.rb`? Or are you looking at a different field to determine that your cookbook didn't change?

Comment: @Martin you may upload the same cookbook version with recipe change (not recommended in prod, but likely to be in dev), and running in debug shows you chef see the recipe has change, even in same version, and it download and use the newer version. So Here it's more like a UI bug or a cache problem. (Kind of off(topic for SO IMHO)

Comment: @Tensibai That's the situation I'm suggesting. What makes you think this isn't what is happening? If the OP is only looking at the version field on the chef server UI, which hasn't changed, but his recipe is performing the changed code when the client runs, then it seems like uploading the same recipe without bumping the version is exactly what he's seeing, no?

Comment: @Martin I assume the OP is smart enough to look at the recipe file on the Web UI and not the metadata.rb has he talk about the recipe content. And you may have a cache issue in the Web UI when you do that (updating on same version).

Comment: @Tensibai Thank you Tensibai, confirmed it was browser issue, only hit Ctrl+F5 won't help, I have to clean temp files and cache. (IE on windows 10)